# What does DataContext="{Binding}" mean?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to find out where the items in a HeaderedContentControl come from in a project that's not mine. Here's the code:

```
        <HeaderedContentControl 
            Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
            Header="Workspaces"
            Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}" 
            DataContext="{Binding}" // <--- this 
       />

<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
<TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
```

so let's examine it:

1. ContentTemplate attribute describes how the items are desplayed.
2. WorkspacesTemplate sets ItemsSource's attribute to {Binding} meaning it's bound to its DataContext property (DataContext of HeaderedContentControl)
3. So I look at HeaderedContentControl's dataContext, but it is described as "{Binding}" as well...

What does that mean?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code it is hard to be certain, but `DataContext="{Binding}"` is quite often unnecessary, as any object in the current binding context will automatically have its `DataContext` property set to the equivalent of `{Binding}`.

Remember:

- `Property="{Binding}"` means "set `this.Property` to the evaluated value of `this.DataContext`"
- `Property="{Binding Path=SubProperty}"` means "set `this.Property` to the evaluated value of `this.DataContext.SubProperty`"
- etc

This means that `DataContext="{Binding}"` means "set `this.DataContext` to the evaluated value of `this.DataContext`", which (in most cases) is redundant!

Comment: I'm intrigued by the "in most cases".  When is it not redundant?

Comment: On it's own I'm *pretty* sure it's always redundant, but there are some valid use cases if you include converters, update triggers etc. to change the behaviour of the binding

Comment: The most common use is to reset a DataContext on controls that have inheritted an overriden DataContext from their parent, back to the original value.

Comment: "reset a DataContext" makes no sense. `DataContext="{Binding}"` is always redundant. Anybody who claims to know about a "valid use" case should be more specific, ideally just show it.

Answer (score 5):

`{Binding}` is something like bind 'this' or current data context - assigned or inherited from parents. For better understanding, equivalent for `{Binding}` is `{Binding .}` or `{Binding Path=.}`