# What is different between {binding} and inherit in wpf datacontext?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have some problems about datacontext binding.

My app has virtualization listbox.

Sometimes Button is not fired dataContextChanged.

So I found this.

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding ~~>
  <Button DataContext={Binding}/>
 </Grid>
```

```
 <Grid DataContext={Binding ~~>
  <Button/>
 </Grid>
```

My Code is first one. but It's not fired DataContextChanged sometimes, So I changed code to second one.

snoop said first one is from inherit, and second one is from parentTemplate.

What is different first one and second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:

SomeProperty={Binding} will bind the SomeProperty to the ENTIRE DataContext object from the parent. SomeProperty does not have to be the DataContext from the child. In this special case I don't think there is any difference, since the DataContext is inherited anyways. You are simply explicitly stating, what is already the default. [Discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968321/what-does-datacontext-binding-mean/13968498)

More Info:

Here is an explanation from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0) for

```
 <Button DataContext={Binding}/>
```

> As long as the binding already has a data context (for example, the
> inherited data context coming from a parent element), and whatever
> item or collection being returned by that context is appropriate for
> binding without requiring further path modification, a binding
> declaration can have no clauses at all: {Binding}. This is often the
> way a binding is specified for data styling, where the binding acts
> upon a collection. For more information, see [Using Entire Objects as a Binding Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#using-entire-objects-as-a-binding-source).

and from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"/>
```

> The above example uses the empty binding syntax: {Binding}. In this
> case, the ListBox inherits the DataContext from a parent DockPanel
> element (not shown in this example). When the path is not specified,
> the default is to bind to the entire object. In other words, in this
> example, the path has been left out because we are binding the
> ItemsSource property to the entire object. (See the Binding to
> collections section for an in-depth discussion.)

In general, the DataContext is inherited from parent elements. So in your 2nd example the button gets the DataContext from the Grid. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#specifying-the-binding-source)

"ItemsControl" are special: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525413/itemssource-vs-datacontext-in-binding-case)

I don't know what ~~ is, is this meant to be a placeholder?

Some more information on Bindings and Markup Extensions:
[Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/binding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
[Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
[Link3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Thank you!! I'm sorry to make confuse. ~~ means certain Property. 1st one and 2nd one are totally same thing right?

Comment: From my knowledge and in this case: yes.

Comment: Btw, since you seem to be new here, you can upvote or accept my answer if it helped you ;-)